# Dart Language Walkthrough - override problem

Tags: flutter, dart

This code snippet from the Dart Language Walk though fails. See section on overridable operators below this section [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#extending-a-class). Any idea why?

```
  class Vector {
   final int x, y;
  
   Vector(this.x, this.y);
  
   Vector operator +(Vector v) => Vector(x + v.x, y + v.y);
   Vector operator -(Vector v) => Vector(x - v.x, y - v.y);
   // use this and the assert will work
   // bool operator ==(Vector v) => x == v.x && y == v.y;
   // See encubus accepted answer below.

  
   Dump() {
     print(this.x);
     print(this.y);
   }


   // Operator == and hashCode not shown. For details, see note below.
   // ···
  }

  final v = Vector(2, 3);
  final w = Vector(2, 2);

  var x = v+w;
  x.dump();
  assert(x == Vector(4,5));
  assert((v + w) == Vector(4, 5));
```

All the asserts fail, but the x.dump() output is 4 and 5. I modified the code to add () around the v + w so it checks the result of the + override in case it was asserting just w and not the sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the `==` operator is not redefined for the Vector class

> // Operator == and hashCode not shown.

You need to implement the `==` for the `Vector` class to use it.

https://api.dart.dev/be/175383/dart-core/Object/operator_equals.html
https://api.dart.dev/be/175383/dart-core/Object/hashCode.html

*If a subclass overrides the equality operator it should override the hashCode method as well to maintain consistency.*

Comment: Many thanks.  I updated the question to provide the code I used as a result of your assistance.